# What's the idiomatic way to make a lookup table which uses field of the item as the key?

Tags: rust

I have a collection of `Foo`.

```
struct Foo {
    k: String,
    v: String,
}
```

I want a `HashMap` which has the key `&foo.k` and the value `foo`.

Apparently, it is not possible without redesigning `Foo` by introducing `Rc` or clone/copy the `k`.

```
fn t1() {
    let foo = Foo { k: "k".to_string(), v: "v".to_string() };
    let mut a: HashMap<&str, Foo> = HashMap::new();
    a.insert(&foo.k, foo); // Error
}
```

There seems to be a workaround by abusing `get()` from `HashSet` ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c3a884d5761736dab76abd8af38ebe13&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher, BuildHasher};
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry::*;

struct Foo {
    k: String,
    v: String,
}

impl PartialEq for Foo {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool { self.k == other.k }
}

impl Eq for Foo {}

impl Hash for Foo {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, h: &mut H) { self.k.hash(h); }
}

impl ::std::borrow::Borrow<str> for Foo {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &str {
        self.k.as_str()
    }
}

fn t2() {
    let foo = Foo { k: "k".to_string(), v: "v".to_string() };
    let mut a: HashSet<Foo> = HashSet::new();
    a.insert(foo);
    let bar = Foo { k: "k".to_string(), v: "v".to_string() };
    let foo = a.get("k").unwrap();
    println!("{}", foo.v);
}
```

This is pretty tedious. What if a `Foo` has multiple fields and different collections of `Foo` to key on different fields?

Comment: `HashMap` exposes an interface that would be unsafe if this were possible; [`get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut) is an example (if you can call this method and values own their keys, it will be possible to invalidate the map). A solution that exposes a safe interface would have to prevent that somehow.

Comment: @trentcl pedantic nit, but it wouldn't be *unsafe* (using the Rust definition), just a logic error.

Comment: @Shepmaster too late to edit, but you're absolutely right. Maybe "unsound" would have been better -- I'm shaky on the semantics of that term

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Apparently, it is not possible without redesigning `Foo` by introducing `Rc` or clone/copy the `k`.

That's correct, it is not possible to have `HashMap<&K, V>` where the key points to some component of the value.

The `HashMap` owns the key and the value, conceptually storing both in big vectors. When a new value is added to the `HashMap`, these existing values might need to be moved around due to hash collisions *or* the vectors might need to be reallocated to hold more items. Both of these operations would invalidate the address of any existing key, leaving it pointing at invalid memory. This would break Rust's safety guarantees, thus it is disallowed.

Read [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423) for a thorough discussion.

Additionally, [trentcl points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43695527/whats-the-idiomatic-way-to-make-a-lookup-table-which-uses-field-of-the-item-as/43696277#comment74437283_43695527) that [`HashMap::get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut) would allow you to get a mutable reference to the *key*, which would allow you to change the key without the map knowing. As the documentation states:

> It is a logic error for a key to be modified in such a way that the key's hash, as determined by the Hash trait, or its equality, as determined by the Eq trait, changes while it is in the map.

---

Workarounds include:

- Remove the key from the struct and store it separately. Instead of `HashMap<&K, V>` where V is `(K, Data)`, store `HashMap<K, Data>`. You can return a struct which glues references to the key and value together ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43566310/155423))
- Share ownership of the key using `Rc` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43656695/155423))
- Create duplicate keys using `Clone` or `Copy`.
- Use a `HashSet` as you have done, enhanced by [Sebastian Redl's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43696278/155423). A `HashSet<K>` is actually just a `HashMap<K, ()>`, so this works by transferring all ownership to the key.

Answer (score 5):

You can introduce a wrapper type for the item stored in the set.

```
struct FooByK(Foo);
```

Then implement the various traits needed for the set for this struct instead. This lets you choose a different wrapper type if you need a set that indexes by a different member.

Comment: I also usually advocate for creating a `key` inherent method that is called from `Eq` and `Ord` and friends, to reduce the chance of them getting out of sync.