# Is there any way to look up in HashSet by only the value the type is hashed on?

Tags: hashmap, rust, hashset

I have a struct that has, among other data, a unique `id`:

```
struct Foo {
    id: u32,
    other_data: u32,
}
```

I want to use the `id` as the key and keep it inside of the struct:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
impl PartialEq for Foo {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Foo) -> bool {
        self.id == other.id
    }
}
impl Eq for Foo {}
impl Hash for Foo {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.id.hash(state);
    }
}
```

This works:

```
pub fn bar() {
    let mut baz: HashSet<Foo> = HashSet::new();
    baz.insert(Foo {
        id: 1,
        other_data: 2,
    });
    let other_data = baz.get(&Foo {
        id: 1,
        other_data: 0,
    }).unwrap()
        .other_data;
    println!("other_data: {}", other_data);
}
```

Is there any way to write `baz.get(1).unwrap().other_data;` instead of `baz.get(&Foo { id: 1, other_data: 0 }).unwrap().other_data;`?

An alternative might be a `HashMap` where the key is contained inside the `struct`. However, I can't have the `id` inside the struct and a duplicate `id` used for the `key`.

Comment: I don't know Rust very well. In reference-based languages (like Java) when this problem comes up, you'd use a boxed key (which you get whether you like it or not in Java) with a reference to it in the HashMap entry key field and another inside the corresponding value object. In a language like C or Ada that allows references/pointers to unboxed types, you can store the value in either place and a reference to it in the other. Afaik Rust collections allow the first solution for sure and maybe the second as well.

Comment: maybe use an enum {Key(u32), KeyAndData(u32,u32)} and implement hash/eq so you can query by key and get keyanddata? That way you won't have to construct the tail of your `Foo`. Anyway, you didn't say why you actually need this, since your toy example already works without modification.

Comment: @Gene Your first point works (see [How can I keep a reference to a key after it has been inserted into a HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32403439/155423)), but you can't have a reference to the key because that solution is not memory-safe (and Rust will tell you so) — the address of the key can change as things are added/removed, so you'd have a dangling pointer. Rust is actually not smart enough to tell that the boxed case is fine, either. See [What's the idiomatic way to make a lookup table which uses field of the item as the key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43695527/155423) for more.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your response. I've only read through the docs of Rust, but it seems to have many ideas I've wished for in a language for a long time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you check out the signature for [`HashSet::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.get), you'll note that it's slightly more complicated than you might expect:

```
fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, value: &Q) -> Option<&T> 
where
    T: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Eq,
```

This is done *precisely to solve your problem*. `get` accepts a reference to any type (`&Q`) that can be borrowed from the type in the set (`T: Borrow<Q>`). `T` should be read as "my type" and `Q` should be read as "the query type".

Thus, you need to implement [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) for your type:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

type Id = u32;

#[derive(Debug, Eq)]
struct Foo {
    id: Id,
    other_data: u32,
}

impl PartialEq for Foo {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Foo) -> bool {
        self.id == other.id
    }
}

impl Hash for Foo {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.id.hash(state);
    }
}

impl Borrow<Id> for Foo {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Id {
        &self.id
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut baz = HashSet::new();
    baz.insert(Foo {
        id: 1,
        other_data: 2,
    });

    let other_data = baz.get(&1).unwrap().other_data;
    println!("other_data: {}", other_data);
}
```

---

See also:

- [What's the idiomatic way to make a lookup table which uses field of the item as the key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43695527/whats-the-idiomatic-way-to-make-a-lookup-table-which-uses-field-of-the-item-as)
- [How can I keep a reference to a key after it has been inserted into a HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401857/how-can-i-keep-a-reference-to-a-key-after-it-has-been-inserted-into-a-hashmap)
- [How to avoid temporary allocations when using complex key for HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480845/how-to-avoid-temporary-allocations-when-using-complex-key-for-hashmap)