# How can I modify properties in a HashSet that are not part of the hash computation?

Tags: rust, hashset

I have a struct that contains a unique id and uses that id for its hash:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

type Id = u32;

#[derive(Debug, Eq)]
struct Foo {
    id: Id,
    other_data: u32,
}

impl PartialEq for Foo {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Foo) -> bool {
        self.id == other.id
    }
}

impl Hash for Foo {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.id.hash(state);
    }
}

impl Borrow<Id> for Foo {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Id {
        &self.id
    }
}
```

I understand that I cannot modify the value of `Foo::id` once I've put it into the `HashSet` because that would change the hash. However, I would like to modify `Foo::other_data`. I know I could remove it from the `HashSet`, modify it, and insert it again, but a method like `get_mut()` would be so much cleaner. Is there a way to accomplish something like this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut baz = HashSet::new();
    baz.insert(Foo {
        id: 1,
        other_data: 2,
    });

    if let Some(x) = baz.get_mut(&1) {
        *x = 3;
    }
}
```

Is this an anti-pattern; should I be using a `HashMap` instead?

[Related to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384928/is-there-any-way-to-look-up-in-hashset-by-only-the-value-the-type-is-hashed-on)

Comment: `Or is this an anti-pattern and I should be using HashMap instead?` I think you hit the nail on the head right there. You want a data structure with an immutable hash part and a mutable non-hash part, which is exactly what `HashMap` gives you.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo My structs contain their unique ids. With a HashMap how do you ensure that the key corresponds to id value the struct contains?

Comment: I would recommend encapsulating it in a hashset-like interface. You can use a hashmap internally and encapsulate the guarantees about the ID.

Answer (score 10):

This is not possible with your current data structure.

`HashSet` deliberately does not provide methods to mutate values. As you have alluded to, mutating a value in a `HashSet` (or the key in a `HashMap`) will invalidate the hash in the majority of cases. The API encourages proper usage and even makes mention of this:

> It is a logic error for an item to be modified in such a way that the item's hash, as determined by the [`Hash`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html) trait, or its equality, as determined by the [`Eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html) trait, changes while it is in the set. This is normally only possible through [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html), [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), global state, I/O, or unsafe code.

This alludes to one way that you can solve your problem, by using interior mutability:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

#[derive(Debug, Eq)]
struct Foo {
    id: Id,
    other_data: Cell<u32>,
}
```

```
fn main() {
    let mut baz = HashSet::new();
    baz.insert(Foo {
        id: 1,
        other_data: Cell::new(2),
    });

    if let Some(x) = baz.get(&1) {
        x.other_data.set(3);
    }
}
```

This is a reasonable thing to do, but I wouldn't be thrilled about doing it. Instead, I would allow my type to be decomposed into a key and a value and store it in a `HashMap`, as mentioned. Something like

```
impl Foo {
    // or insert_into_hashmap(self, &mut HashMap<Id, u32>)
    fn into_key_value(self) -> (Id, u32) {
        (self.id, self.other_data)
    }

    // Maybe a
    //
    // fn from_key_value(&'a Id, &'a u32) -> Self
    // or
    // fn from_hashmap(Id, &HashMap<Id, u32>) -> Self
}

// Maybe a
//
// struct FooRef<'a> { (or FooRefMut?) 
//     id: &'a Id,
//     other_data: &'a u32,
// }
//
// With a
// fn from_key_value(&'a Id, &'a u32) -> Self
// or
// fn from_hashmap(Id, &HashMap<Id, u32>) -> Self

fn main() {
    let mut baz = HashMap::new();
    let f = Foo {
        id: 1,
        other_data: 2,
    };
    let (k, v) = f.into_key_value();
    baz.insert(k, v);

    // See also HashMap::get_key_value
    if let Some(v) = baz.get_mut(&1) {
        *v = 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe `unsafe` code is the best route in this case.

```
impl Foo {
    fn set_other_data(set: &mut HashSet<Foo>, id: &Id, data: u32) -> bool{
        match set.get(id) {
            Some(x) => {
                let p: *const Foo = x;
                let q: *mut Foo = p as *mut Foo;
                unsafe {
                    (*q).other_data = data;
                }
                return true;
            }
            None => return false,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut baz = HashSet::new();
    baz.insert(Foo {
        id: 1,
        other_data: 2,
    });

    Foo::set_other_data(&mut baz, &1, 3);
    assert_eq!(3, baz.get(&1).unwrap().other_data);
}
```

As Shepmaster quoted:

> It is a logic error for an item to be modified in such a way that the item's hash, as determined by the [`Hash`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html) trait, or its equality, as determined by the [`Eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html) trait, changes while it is in the set. This is normally only possible through [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html), [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), global state, I/O, or unsafe code.

In this case `other_data` is not used by the `Hash` or `Eq` traits. So it can safely be mutated. The largest danger is that at a later point `Hash for Foo` or `Eq for Foo` would be modified and include `other_data`.

There is no danger of data races because the `HashSet<Foo>` is mutably borrowed.

Other options:

Decomposing: This works when `Foo` has only 2 elements, but suppose `Foo` contains many elements. Do you decompose `Foo` into all of its individual elements (seems messy) or create sub-structs within `Foo` (code bloat).

Encapsulation: Silvio Mayolo suggested encapsulating `Foo` in a `HashSet` like interface that internally uses `HashMap`. This keeps the API clean and uses only `safe` code, but seems like more programming then is necessary.

I would appreciate your feedback and if this seems reasonable I can put in a feature request for an `unsafe fn get_mut()` for `HashSet`.

Comment: I believe this code cause undefined behavior and cannot recommend it. Here's a [small example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9ae49d432427a44e6f57cf8151b1ea95) where Miri detects violations.

Comment: no you are not allowed to do this, you can't mutate something that should be const `set.get(id)`

Comment: @Shepmaster Miri complains that `error[E0080]: constant evaluation error: borrow being accessed (Alias(None)) does not exist on the borrow stack`. However, there is no fear of any other thread mutating the `HashSet` in the code I gave above because the `HashSet` is mutably borrowed: `set: &mut HashSet<Foo>`. I don't see what the undefined behavior would be.

Comment: @HiDefender threading has nothing to do with undefined behavior. The Rust compiler is allowed to assume that *nothing* mutates the referred-to value of an immutable reference, unless there's an [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html): *In general, transmuting an `&T` type into an `&mut T` is considered undefined behavior.*