# HashMap with key referring a field in the value

Tags: rust

I want to create a hash map from a vector of entities. I want the key to be a reference to a field in the corresponding value. This is something I have come up with.

```rust
struct Entity {
    id: String,
    patterns: Vec<Pattern>,
}

struct Package<'ent> {
    entity_map: HashMap<&'ent String, Entity>,
}

impl<'ent> Package<'ent> {
    fn from(entities: Vec<Entity>) -> Self {
        let entity_map: HashMap<&String, Entity> =
            entities.into_iter().map(|e| (&e.id, e)).collect();
        Package { entity_map }
    }
}
```

Of course, this isn't working. I am pretty new to Rust. Is there anything wrong with this approach? How can I achieve what I want? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See the above-linked duplicate. Also, consider this: borrowing from a value in the map requires borrowing the map itself. But you need a mutable borrow to add more items to the map, so _even if lifetimes let you do this,_ as soon as you added the first element, the map would be frozen as it borrows itself and you would be unable to add a second element. If you want part of the value to be the key, you might want to use `HashSet` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think your best bet is to have the `HashMap`'s keys and values both be references to elements in the original `Vec`, which should itself be passed by reference (as a slice, the more general version of `&Vec`) instead of by value.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Pattern;

struct Entity {
    id: String,
    patterns: Vec<Pattern>,
}

struct Package<'ent> {
    // Now the values are references too
    entity_map: HashMap<&'ent String, &'ent Entity>,
}

impl<'ent> Package<'ent> {
    // Package<'ent> can be constructed from any slice that outlives it
    fn from(entities: &'ent [Entity]) -> Self {
        let entity_map = entities
            .iter()
            .map(|e| (&e.id, e))
            .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>();
        Package { entity_map }
    }
}
```

As an aside, if you're implementing the function `from(T)`, you probably want to do so as part of the implementation of the trait `From<T>` for your type.

---

If you can't store the vector for long enough to make the above solution work, then you can simply split `Entity` into its key and value components, which can then be used as owned values in the HashMap.

```
// Same Pattern and Entity as above

struct EntityValue {
    patterns: Vec<Pattern>,
}

impl Package {
    fn from(entities: Vec<Entity>) -> Self {
        let entity_map = entities
            .into_iter()
            .map(|e| {
                let Entity { id, patterns } = e;
                (id, EntityValue { patterns })
            })
            .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>();
        Package { entity_map }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is an enlightening solution. But the original use-case was deserializing it from yaml (where it's serialized as a list), which I think, wouldn't fit this solution.

Comment: If your problem is that the input vector only exists for the duration of deserialization, but not after, then yep that's a problem. You could do your deserialization in two steps, first into a vector and then use that vector (which would persist more or less for the duration of your program) to construct the Package. Another solution is to remove the `id` from `Entity` — then you could have owned strings as keys and owned Entities (sans `id`) as values in your HashMap.

Comment: That can also be a solution, but I would like `id` to be owned by `Entity` since it would result into cleaner implementations for the other methods. I think I would follow @cdhowie's suggestion of using `HashSet`. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45390990/19058767) fits my solution perfectly. But thank you for your help. Really appreciate it!